# Show that operator Is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis

I try to show that an operator given by formula

$$ A[(x1,x2,x3)] = [x1+x2;2x1+x3;x2-2x3]$$

is linear and bounded. Linearity is quite obvious, but I can't proof that it is bounded.
I know that operator is bounded if

$$ ||Au||_2 \le M||u||_2 $$

I'm using second norm. Also I need to know the appropriate M. How can I find
it? My attempt was to expand the squares in the left hand side in norm, but I can't see what to do next.

Comment: Familiar with eigenvalues and condition number of a matrix?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin yes, but I think there is a solution without them, because there was no information in the course about them

Comment: @JackHavis Yes it can be. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So we are given that
$$A\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\2&0&1\\0&1&-2\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}\uparrow & \uparrow &\uparrow\\Ae_1 & Ae_2&Ae_3\\\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow\end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}.$$

$$A\mathbf{x}=x(Ae_1)+y(Ae_2)+z(Ae_3).$$
So
\begin{align*}
\|A \mathbf{x}\|_2 & =\|x(Ae_1)+y(Ae_2)+z(Ae_3)\|_2\\
& \leq |x|\|Ae_1\|_2+|y|\|Ae_2\|_2+|z|\|Ae_3\|_2 & (\triangle-\text{inequality} )\\
&=|x|\sqrt{5}+|y|\sqrt{2}+|z|\sqrt{5}\\
& \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2} \,\, \sqrt{5+2+5} & (\text{Cauchy Schwarz inequality})\\
&=\sqrt{12}\|\mathbf{x}\|_2.
\end{align*}
Thus we have $\|A\mathbf{x}\|_2 \leq \sqrt{12} \, \|\mathbf{x}\|_2$, so $A$ is bounded and $M=\sqrt{12}$.

Note: Linear operator between finite dimensional spaces is always bounded. Also note that $\|A\|_2=\text{Trace}(A^TA)$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that with your approach you got as far as expanding the squares in the norm of the left hand side and got somewhere like:

${x_1}^2 + 2{x_1}{x_2} + {x_2}^2 + 4{x_1}^2 + 4{x_1}{x_3} + {x_3}^2 + {x_2}^2 - 4{x_2}{x_3} + 4{x_3}^2$

$= 5{x_1}^2 + 2{x_2}^2 + 5{x_3}^2 + 2{x_1}{x_2} + 4{x_1}{x_3} - 4{x_2}{x_3}$

Presumably this is the point you got stuck at. To finish your approach, one thing you can do is the following:

$\leq 5{x_1}^2 + 2{x_2}^2 + 5{x_3}^2 + 2\lvert x_1 \rvert \lvert x_2 \rvert + 4 \lvert x_1 \rvert \lvert x_3 \rvert + 4 \lvert x_2 \rvert \lvert x_3 \rvert$

Suppose $x_i$ is the maximum of $\{\lvert x_1 \rvert ,\lvert x_2 \rvert,\lvert x_3 \rvert\}$
Then:

$\leq 5{x_i}^2 + 2{x_i}^2 + 5{x_i}^2 + 2{x_i}^2 + 4{x_i}^2 + 4{x_i}^2$ (as everything here is now positive)

$ = 22{x_i}^2$

$< 23({x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 + {x_3}^2)$ as one of the three squared terms is equal to ${x_i}^2$

Then you can simply take the squareroot to get to the inequality you were looking for, so $\sqrt{23}$ was an acceptable $M$.

Obviously this isn't as tight of a bound as the answer above gave, but I thought it might be valuable to show you an easy way to finish your initial attemp, without having to make use of things that you might not be familiar with yet.